# Replace specials characters with sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to use a sed command to replace specials characters in my file.
The characters are `%>` to replace by `]`.
I'am using  `sed -r s/\%>\/\]\/g` but i have this error `bash: /]/g: No such file or directory`, looks like sed doesn't like it.

Comment: add quotes around command: `sed -r 's/\%>\/\]\/g'`

Comment: @mouviciel it won't work since you escaped the delimiters.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - You are correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement [Avinash Raj's correct and helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29748507/45375):

Since you were using an overall unquoted string (neither single- nor double-quoted), you were on the right track by `\`-escaping *individual* characters in your `sed` command.

However, **you neglected to `\`-quote `>`, which is what caused your problem**:

- `>` is one of the shell's so-called *metacharacters*
- Metacharacters have special meaning and *separate words*
- Thus, `s/\%>\/\]\/g` is mistakenly split into *2* arguments by `>`:

  - `s/\%` is passed to `sed` - as `s/%`, because the shell removes the `\` instances (a process called *quote removal*).

    - As you can see, this is not a valid `sed` command, but that doesn't even come into play - see below.
  - `>\/\]\/g` is interpreted by the *shell* (`bash`), because it starts with output-redirection operator `>`; after quote removal, the shell sees `>/]/g`, tries to open *file* `/]/g` for writing, and fails, because your system doesn't have a subdirectory named `]` in its root directory.
- `bash` tries to open an output file specified by a redirection *before* running the command and, if it fails to open the file, *does not run the command* - which is what happened here:

  - `bash` complained about the nonexistent target directory and aborted processing of the command - *`sed` was never even invoked*.

**Upshot:**

- In a string that is neither enclosed in single nor in double-quotes, you must  `\`-quote:

  - all metacharacters: `|  & ; ( ) < > space tab`
  - additionally, to prevent accidental pathname expansion (globbing): `* ? [`
  - Also note that if you need to quote (escape) characters *for `sed`*,you need to add an *extra layer of quoting*; for instance to instruct `sed` to use a *literal* `.` in the regex, you must pass `\\.` - *two* backslashes - so that `sed` sees the properly escaped `\.`.
- Given the above, **it is much simpler to *(habitually) use single quotes* around your `sed` command**, because it ensures that the string is passed *as is* to `sed`.

Let's compare a *working* version of your command to the one from [Avinash Raj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29748507/45375) (leaving out the `-r` for brevity):

```
sed  s/\%\>\/\]\/g  # ok - all metachars. \-quoted, others are, but needn't be quoted
sed  s/%\>/]/g      # ok - minimum \-quoting
sed 's/%>/]/g'      # simplest: single-quoted command
```

Comment: thanks a lot explaination really clear, in fact @Avinash Raj's answer is good but without your explanation i would never understand why !

Comment: one more question how can i associate to commande like that if i want to replace  2 differents characters

Comment: @iceman225: Sorry, I don't understand. Are you talking about a character _set_ in a regular expression, such as `[ab]` to match a single character that is either 'a' _or_ 'b'?

Comment: i have `<% ` and  `%>` to replace in my file so i want to make one synthax with sed to replace both of them.

Comment: @iceman225: It's simplest to string together 2 `s` commands, separated by `;`: `sed 's/%>/]/g; s/<%/[/g'`. If you have further questions, I suggest you create a _new_ question.

Answer (score 4):

Put your sed code inside quotes and also add the file-path you want to work with and finally don't escape the sed delimiters.

```
$ echo '%>' | sed 's/%>/]/g'
]
```

ie,

```
sed 's/%>/]/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I got the question correctly. If you want to replace either `%` or `>` by  `]` then `sed` is not required here. Use `tr` in this case:

```
tr '%>' ']' < input.txt
```

If you want to replace the sequence `%>` by `]` then the `sed` command as shown by @AvinashRaj is the way to go.

Comment: It seems that the question is for the peer of character together (based on the sed action using `s` and not `t` or a class character in `s`).

Comment: @NeronLeVelu The `t` command does not do what you might think of it in `sed`